# Android handles third-party requests to update page elements

Tags: java, android, websocket

Use java to develop Android applications, update the elements of the page after receiving a request from a third partyI use Socket here, what else can I use?

Since I use Socket, I can't return the status of my current execution to the third-party service (e.g. whether I updated successfully), so I want to replace it

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe you should [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.